# Passing on missing quasiquotation arguments

Tags: r, rlang, quasiquotes

I am trying to use the quasiquotation to pass a raw variable name to a function, that passes it on to another function. However, the argument is optional, so I need to test if the 1st function was not given the argument and passed on that missing argument to the 2nd function.

In these examples `b` refers to a variable in a data.frame.

Testing if a function was passed a raw variable expression or no argument, I do

```
foo <- function(a) {
  print(is_missing(enexpr(a)))
}
foo()
# [1] TRUE
foo(b)
# [1] FALSE
```

Without the `enexpr`, the variable `b` will attempt to be evaluated - and when missing - Errors.

Next, I try to pass the missing argument to another function (`bar`) whom then will test for its presence:

```
foo2 <- function(a) {
  print(is_missing(enexpr(a)))
  bar(maybe_missing(a))
}
bar <- function(a) {
  print(is_missing(enexpr(a)))
}
foo2()
# [1] TRUE 
# [1] FALSE  <-- "wrong" (but not unexpected)
foo2(b)
# [1] FALSE
# [1] FALSE
```

**Question:** How can I in `bar` test whether `foo2` was passed an argument?

Running R 3.5.1 with rlang 0.3.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do a `!!` and an `enexpr` in `foo2`

```
foo2 <- function(a) {
  print(is_missing(enexpr(a)))
  bar(!!maybe_missing(enexpr(a)))
}

foo2()
#[1] TRUE
#[1] TRUE

foo2(b)
#[1] FALSE
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks akrun. Still struggling to understand quasiquotation. Will have to re-read the chapters in Hadley's Advanced R...